# Calculate Percentage XP Completed out of 100

Tags: javascript, php, math

Well I have seen many questions for calculating Percentage, but I have my different case

I have a table which says:

```
id | xp_required | level
-------------------------
1  |  65         | 1
-------------------------
2  |  215        | 2
```

Lets say my current xp is 66 and required to complete 100% is 215 so I need to calculate how many percentage is completed. Please note that I need **differential** percentage: in my previous example at 65exp I would have 0% in the path for level 2.

I am applying this formula but not sure is this correct or not

```
Percent to next level = Experience from current level / Experience required to advance to next level
```

Any changes shall I required?

Comment: If you give us an idea in which variable you current expirience is stored I guess a lot of people are able to help you with your question.
E.g.: Assuming `curExp` contains your curren Expirience amount. then `curExp/xp_required _i` where i is your current level, would be an appropriate answer :)

Comment: @Kennuel Current XP is the value which I have made bold will go there

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get the current **global** progress:

```
CurPercentage = 100 * ( CurExp/ExpRequired );
```

To get the *remaining* percentage:

```
RemainingPercentage = 100 - CurPercentage;
```

Now let's say you want the percentage progress *from* the last level. For example, if level 1 is reached at 65 exp, having exactly 65 points means being at 0% in the path for level 2. For level N:

```
CurRelativePercentageLevelN = 100 * (CurExp -ExpRequired (N-1))/(ExpRequired(N) - ExpRequired(N-1));
```

*Remaining* percentage:

```
RemainingRelativePercentageLevelN = 100 - CurRelativePercentageLevelN;
```

Comment: Yet it is giving me wrong let say i ahve current xp is 66 and to required to complete 100 % I should be having 215 then it will give me wrong result

Comment: If you have 66 and you have to reach 215, you are at 100*66/215 of progress = 30.7%. 100-30.7 = 69.3% is missing.

Comment: Cubo78 is right. Basically that's an exact same solution, as mine <_>

Comment: But at 65 level 1 is there! so dont you think between level 2 and level 1, percentage should be calculated

Comment: @Jaymin, I edited the answer explaining how to get he *differential* percentage to progress from level N to level N+1. If it isn't what you need I surrender.

Answer (score 1):

```
percent_to_next_level = xp_current / (xp_required / 100)
```

Comment: miss brackets, sorry, fixed

Comment: Yet it is giving me wrong let say i ahve current xp is 66 and to required to complete 100 % I should be having 215 then it will give me wrong result